# Camera Follow for 2D - GameObjects Blink Out Upon Jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Yes, I read through about 30 different similar titles before posting this. However, there wasn't anything relevant to what I need. I'm trying to set my camera's Y-axis to follow the player as it moves through the level; however, I don't want the camera to move up and down whilst jumping so I follow the camera's transform.position.y and NOT the player's.

```
 void Pjump()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && onFloor==true 
        || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && onFloor==true)
    {


            player.velocity = new Vector2(0, jump);
            onFloor = false;
        isJumping = true;  // Static Variable to pass onto CamFollow script


    }

}
```

isJumping is set false inside an OnCollisionEnter2d() and called inside of a FixedUpdate().

Now for the CamFollow script

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class CamFollow : MonoBehaviour
 {


private GameObject p1;

private bool isFollow;

[Header("Camera Offset Values")]
[SerializeField]
private float xOff;
[SerializeField]
private float yOff;

void Start()
{
    p1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    isFollow = true;

}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isFollow)
    {

       if (Pmove.isJumping == false) // This code works fine
       {
            transform.position = new Vector3(p1.transform.position.x + xOff, p1.transform.position.y + yOff,
                                                                                                      transform.position.z);
        }

       if(Pmove.isJumping == true) // This is where the problem is: Y-Axis
        {

            transform.position = new Vector3(p1.transform.position.x + xOff, transform.position.y + yOff,
                                                                                                     transform.position.z);

        }


    }
  }
 }
```

When the player jumps, the player and all non-UI objects vanish until the player touches the ground.

Comment: I suspect that you are going past your camera's far clipping plane. I think you want to have your y position to be "transform.position.y" and NOT "transform.position.y + yOff", because adding the yOff in this branch will move your camera on the Y axis (probably moving everything past the far clipping plane), which you said you do not want to happen while jumping.

Comment: Oh, forgot to add that in the post. My offset just makes the camera align on play so the player isn't in the middle of the screen. If I want the camera to shake upon enemy collision, I can use the offsets. Ultimately, the only camera control is the coordinates. My far clipping plane is set to 20 and near is 0.1. It's a 2D side scroller. Should I re-adjust the planes? Just want to add that I've tested both lines of code individually and they both work. But put them into an IF statement and the jump causes this error. So I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @adisib Actually, your answer was 100% correct. I removed the offest from the Y-axis int the Pmove.isJumping == true and the code works perfectly. If you publish your answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: And all you'd really need to do is copy my code above and just remove the (+ yOff) in the isJumping == true check.